# Getting 'unencrypted_secret' when trying to login bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket

I'm trying to login bitbucket with two-step verification, but I'm getting this error:

> field `unencrypted_secret` is deprecated.

[image: field <code>unencrypted_secret</code> is deprecated]

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlassian Bitbucket [said](https://twitter.com/Bitbucket/status/1053432063695695872):

> This is a known issue and should be fixed now. ^Lewis

So... this happens a lot..